# How to randomize questions without repetition from SQLite?

Tags: android, random, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm developing a simple quiz in my android studio. I'm using a database but I would like to randomize the questions every time the user clicks on the quiz button. I have created 5 sample questions so far.

Comment: You are missing the part of the code that involves "clicking on the quiz button"

Comment: I think you're showing the wrong piece of code, after you populate your data from the db, rearrange your List.  I think you're looking for randomization techniques.

Comment: Use `... ORDER BY RANDOM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Collections.shuffle` on your `List<Question>`, then use an `Iterator<Question>` to pick out the questions as you click a button.

Assuming you implemented both `equals` and `hashcode` for your `Question` class, then a `LinkedHashSet` will remove the duplicates, so repetition won't happen.

Here is an Activity based on your class that should show these concepts.

```
public class QuizActivityMarketing extends Activity {

    private Iterator<Question> questionIterator;
    private TextView txtQuestion;
    private RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc, rdd;
    private Button butNext;

    private Question currentQ;
    private int score = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Define your views
        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rda = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rdd = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        butNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // Get and randomize the questions
        DbHelperMarketing db = new DbHelperMarketing(this);
        final List<Question> questions = db.getAllQuestions();
        Collections.shuffle(questions);
        questionIterator = new LinkedHashSet<Question>(questions).iterator();

        // Setup the first question
        if (questionIterator.hasNext()) {
            currentQ = questionIterator.next();
            setQuestionView(currentQ);
        }

        // Hook up the button-clicking
        butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Check the correct answer
                RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());
                if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())) {
                    score++;
                    Log.d("score", "Your score" + score);
                }

                // Load the next question, if there are any
                if (questionIterator.hasNext()) {
                    currentQ = questionIterator.next();
                    setQuestionView(currentQ);
                } else { // Done asking questions
                    setQuestionView(null);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivityMarketing.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setQuestionView(Question currentQuestion) {
        if (currentQuestion != null) {
            txtQuestion.setText(currentQuestion.getQUESTION());
            rda.setText(currentQuestion.getOPTA());
            rdb.setText(currentQuestion.getOPTB());
            rdc.setText(currentQuestion.getOPTC());
            rdd.setText(currentQuestion.getOPTD());
        } else {
            txtQuestion.setText("");
            rda.setText("");
            rdb.setText("");
            rdc.setText("");
            rdd.setText("");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm actually new to Java, so I was just wondering if you can explain what this means?

Comment: Sure. Before I go too far, you are returning a List from your SQLite `getAllQuestions` method. I assume you know how to use that method and where to call it?

Comment: Yes, I am calling it in another class. QuizActivityMarketing.java This is the class is called when the user clicks the "quiz button"

Comment: If you include that Activity code with [an edit to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35756604/edit), I could explain it better

Comment: Read the edits, then let me know if you would like more of an explanation

Comment: Any reason you removed int qid=0?

Comment: Do you need it? The only thing I saw it being used for was an index in the list.

Comment: I seem to be getting an error. It says "Incompatible types. Required: Iterator <java.lang.String> Found: <com.turnerfentondeca.decaturnerfenton.Question>"

The error appears at this code " questionIterator = new LinkedHashSet<Question>(questions).iterator();

Comment: Ooops, sorry, check again. I changed the `Iterator<String>` at the top

Comment: You can keep `qId` if you only want to ask 5 questions, but this code will ask every question from the SQLite database.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked. Your help is very much appreciated. I know this is asking too much, but do you have an idea of how I can display the users score after they answer the 5 questions?

Comment: From `ResultActivity`, in `onCreate`, you should be able to use `getIntent` to get the data that you passed into it from `QuizActivityMarketing`. You just need to do something like `int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("score", 0)` where 0 is the "default value" if the "score" key was not found in the Intent.

Comment: Would that display the score? And If I want to give different comments depending on their score, I just use a simple if and else statement correct?

Comment: That would get the value of the score. You would still need to put it into a TextView with `setText(""+score)` (be careful with setText, since it also allows int parameters). And yup, regular if-else for any conditions you want to set on the scores

Comment: For some reason, the score displayed is always "0". Even if I answer the questions corretly

Comment: Like I said, if the Intent does not contain the key "score", it will default to 0.

Comment: So how would I fix that? Would you like to see the ResultActivity class?

Comment: If the process demonstrated here doesn't fix it, then sure. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7325248/2308683

Comment: The link you posted has a great solution, but unfortunately, I'm not sure what I should be putting in my code. What do I input as the value? Any way you can explain more?

Comment: The first code block is already in your onClick method for starting the next activity and sending the score with a `Bundle`. The second code block should be placed in `onCreate` of ResultActivity and use `getInt` as I mentioned before, instead of `getString`

Comment: You make Intent, then put extras into it, then start the next activity, and get extras out. That is the simplest explanation I can provide. The only other reason you should be getting 0 is if this condition isn't actually true. `currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())`

Comment: The new variable name would be "score"?

Comment: Name it whatever is easiest for you... You have `b.putInt("score", score);`, so doing `int score = extras.getInt("score");` makes sense to me. 
 `

Comment: I edited my question to show a little of the ResultActivity.java class. I am not sure how to output the score as it says "Variable score is never used"

Comment: Did you make a field named score? Remove `int` from the front of `int score = extras.getInt("score");` or move the `setText` inside the if-statement.

Comment: The score displayed is still "0". I have posted the entire ResultActivity class for you

Comment: Well, the problem lays in the Question asking code for when you do `score++`, then. If you can't see `Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);` in the Logcat, then that is a sign that it isn't working

Comment: How would I fix that? Could the problem be that my DbHelperMarketing class is wrong and it can't find the answer? The only place I have put the answer for the question is in the "Add Question" method in the DbHelperMarketing class. The answer is the last part of the question, ie. "B", or "C". Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, the logcat does not show that. It only shows the yourans (which is the value chosen by the user)

Comment: Do the strings look the same on the yourans line? There may be additional spacing, so you could do `currentQ.getANSWER().trim()`

Comment: The problem still persists. I have edited my entire question to match the code that I have in front of me. Maybe you can spot the error?

Comment: `getANSWER()` looks like it returns `"B"`, for example. That **does not equal** the string that would be returned by `getOPTB()`. When I asked "Do the strings look the same on the yourans line?" I meant you should be seeing `answer answer`, and **not** `B answer`

Comment: Ohh I apologize. That was my fault. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Change the last parameter of the Question object to the  string that is the actual answer instead of "B", for example

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I really appreciate all your help. You were amazing! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing:

## Option1: If you don't want duplicate Questions

1. Use collections, since Sets doesn't allow duplicates and lists can be shuffled
2. Adapt (if not already) your class Question, so you can used in the Set and so not allowing duplicates...(by this **override equals AND hashcode**)
3. populate the Collection, shuffle it, get a random element of it

---

## Option2: If you only want one of the questions at random

this is quite the same,

1. instead of using a set use a list...
2. omit step 2 since duplicated questions are no a big deal...
3. but still populate the Collection, shuffle it, get a random element of it

and there you are :)

Comment: I don't think the OP was concerned about duplicates

Comment: ohhh I miss interpreted the question... thnxs !!

Comment: welcome, also, I don't think a shuffle is ever really necessary because you can take a random index from 0 to the length of the list